# perl issue for gdata in R when import local xls files

Tags: r, perl, gdata

According to [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940224/gdata-package-perl-issue) which have similar issue.

From the link, it mentioned we should set the perl manually.

i do found perl file under the gdata packages folders.

For details the error message is shown below.

```
> list.files()
[1] "fwfdata1.txt"   "fwfdata2.txt"   "txtdata1.txt"   "txtdata2.txt"   "txtdata3.txt"   "txtdata4.txt"  
[7] "xlsdata1.xls"   "xlsxdata1.xlsx"
> #xls data1 - gdata
> 
> library(gdata)
> path <- "xlsdata1.xls"
> data8 <- read.xls(path, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE)
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

So i would like to know how i should set the perl statement.
Besides perl issue, it also appears file.exists(tfn) problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do one of the following:

**1) perl argument** Use the `perl=` argument as indicated in the error message.  First make sure that you did install perl.  Then assuming a Microsoft Windows environment and that perl was installed in `C:\Perl64` (so that `perl.exe` is found at `C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe`) then it would be:

```
read.xls(path, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, perl="C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe")
```

or the same but with forward slashes: `"C:/Perl64/bin/perl"`.

**2) set path** If you don't want to specify `perl=` each time then with the same assumptions regarding the location of perl on your system, ensure that `C:\Perl64\bin` is on your Windows path.  If you have done this correctly then from the Windows cmd line this should find perl:

```
where perl
```

The Windows path can be set through the Windows control panel.  If you do that then the `read.xls` statement you used should work.

**Other OS** If you are not using Windows then take analogous steps to either specify the perl argument or ensure that perl is on your path.