# Read xls file with text wrapped using R

Tags: r

How do you read in an .xls file in R, where the texts is wrapped?

I have tried `read_excel("Data.xls")`, but it returns a 0x0 dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried `readxl::read_xls("Data.xls")`? you may have to convert your file into `.xlsx` format.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to convert the file in R?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of how to change a `.xls` file to `.xlsx` in R. Have you `gdata::read.xls()` which is promissing as it retains the `.xls` format in its read function. Also might be worth trying  `XLConnect`. If you could make your xls file available one could explore read options.

Comment: It works! But it requires Perl (download: http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) and see the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940224/gdata-package-perl-issue

Comment: If the comment is useful, then it is customary to click the uptick symbol so that others in future can see what is helpful.

Comment: I've included the comment as an answer as I suspect this will help others in the same situation and its more obvious if an answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gdata::read.xls(...)`; you may need to install Perl.